# Wait for arbitrary process and get its exit code in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a way to wait until a process finishes if I'm not the one who started it?

e.g. if I ran "ps -ef" and pick any PID (assuming I have rights to access process information) - is there a way I can wait until the PID completes and get its exit code?

Comment: `while kill -0 $pid; do sleep 0.5; done` can poll an arbitrary process, however, the exit code can't be retrieved.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `strace`, which tracks signals and system calls. The following command waits until a program is done, then prints its exit code:

```
$ strace -e none -e exit_group -p $PID       # process calls exit(1)
Process 23541 attached - interrupt to quit
exit_group(1)                          = ?
Process 23541 detached

$ strace -e none -e exit_group -p $PID       # ^C at the keyboard
Process 22979 attached - interrupt to quit
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 22979 detached

$ strace -e none -e exit_group -p $PID       # kill -9 $PID
Process 22983 attached - interrupt to quit
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

Signals from `^Z`, `fg` and `kill -USR1` get printed too. Either way, you'll need to use `sed` if you want to use the exit code in a shell script.

If that's too much shell code, you can use a [program I hacked together in C](https://gitlab.com/monpid/monpid/blob/master/monpid.c) a while back. It uses `ptrace()` to catch signals and exit codes of pids. (It has rough edges and may not work in all situations.)

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way I can wait until the PID completes and get its exit code

Yes, if the process is not being `ptrace`d by somebody else, you can `PTRACE_ATTACH` to it, and get notified about various events (e.g. signals received), and about its exit.

Beware, this is quite complicated to handle properly.

Comment: will it work for arbitrary process?

from http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace - 

The ptrace() system call provides a means by which a **parent** process may observe and control the execution of another process...

Comment: @user1296013 Yes, it will work for arbitrary process (that isn't being ptraced already) for which you have permission (e.g. if you can kill it). Once you `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..)` it, you *become* the parent.

Comment: @EmployedRussian You should really add this in [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 3):

If you can live without the exit code:

```
tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the process ID you can make use of the `wait` command which is a bash builtin:

```
wait PID
```

You can get the PID of the last command run in bash using `$!`. Or, you can grep for it with from the output of `ps`.

In fact, the wait command is a useful way to run parralel command in bash. Here's an example:

```
# Start the processes in parallel...
./script1.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid1=$!
./script2.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid2=$!
./script3.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid3=$!
./script4.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid4=$!

# Wait for processes to finish...
echo -ne "Commands sent... "
wait $pid1
err1=$?
wait $pid2
err2=$?
wait $pid3
err3=$?
wait $pid4
err4=$?

# Do something useful with the return codes...
if [ $err1 -eq 0 -a $err2 -eq 0 -a $err3 -eq 0 -a $err4 -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "pass"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: Yes. But wanted to add that you can only wait for exit code of the pid if that pid is one of your children.

Comment: This only works in the shell from which the original process was invoked; not for an arbitrary process.